What happens in memory when ownership transfer happens
Im struggling to fully grasp what happens to the memory part during ownership transfer.
if a value is owned by one variable and transferred to another, what happens to the memory in the original variable's stack frame after the transfer
As an example, t is out of scope, but test still works. Where is Test(1) stored, and how is it still valid after the block ends if its created in the stack?
struct Test(u8);

impl Drop for Test {
   fn drop(&mut self) {
      println!("{} is dropped", self.0);
  }
}

fn main() {
   let test;
   {
       println!("step 1");
       let t = Test(1);
       println!("step 2");
       test = t;
   } 
   println!("{}", test.0);
}

output:
step 1
step 2
1
1 is dropped

When an owner goes out of scope, Rust automatically clean-up the data associated with that owner by reclaiming memory.
Here's an example that seems to contradict it:
fn main() {
   println!("step 1");
   let test = create_struct();
   println!("step 2");
   println!("{}", test.0);
}

pub fn create_struct() -> Test {
   Test(1)
}

output:
step 1 
step 2 
1 
1 is dropped 

If memory is reclaimed when an owner goes out of scope, how does returning a value from a function prevent this?
Judging from the output of the first example, it's not copied because only one instance of Test was dropped, also that means the stack memory wasn't reclaimed in the inner block or what is happening here?

Does this answer your question? What are move semantics in Rust?

Only I didn't understand anything

I'd advise you to stop worrying about what "happens in memory." Part of the reason is because the answer can vary based on things like the compiler version or the optimization level. Moves and copies can be elided. Secondly, what "happens in memory" is usually irrelevant; what we're actually interested in is the semantics of the language. What happens in memory is just a means to realize those semantics on hardware.

Disclaimer: what actually happens in memory is difficult to pinpoint due to optimizations. For example, a variable doesn't need to be stored in memory at all, it could be in a CPU register. The remainder of this answer assumes that the variables are stored in memory in the "obvious" way.

if a value is owned by one variable and transferred to another, what happens to the memory in the original variable's stack frame after the transfer

It remains unused (or gets reused for storing other variables, with optimization).

As an example, t is out of scope, but test still works. Where is Test(1) stored, and how is it still valid after the block ends if its created in the stack?

It is first stored in t, then moved (bitwise-copied) to test. After the move, the memory in t is no longer relevant.

If memory is reclaimed when an owner goes out of scope, how does returning a value from a function prevent this?

It prevents this by moving the value to another location. If you just called create_struct(); without assigning the value to anything, it would indeed get dropped. By assigning it to a variable, you effectively extend its life.

Judging from the output of the first example, it's not copied because only one instance of Test was dropped

That's correct - it wasn't copied, it was moved. Unlike C++, Rust doesn't do implicit copies, you have to call .clone() explicitly, and then that value is moved.

also that means the stack memory wasn't reclaimed in the inner block or what is happening here?

The stack memory gets reclaimed once the function returns. Before that, moving or dropping the value doesn't reclaim the memory due to how stack works.

thanks for the response. I know that it was "moved", I just don't know how that translates in the memory or what it means (what is bitwise copy?). is it like copied into some new memory or what exactly?
Can you please use both examples to show case what might happen to (1st example: t and 2nd example the memory allocated by the return value)

@kyles Regarding bitwise copy, that just means that data is copied exactly as-is. For example, moving a Vec<T> means that only the 24 bytes that comprise the Vec on the stack (one pointer to data and two usizes, for length and capacity) are copied to the new location, and the old location is forgotten and remains inaccessible to Rust code. That's a bitwise/shallow copy, and it's very efficient as it doesn't touch individual Ts stored by the Vec on the heap.

@kyles * I know that it was "moved", I just don't know how that translates in the memory* - it means the memory was copied to the new location, and the contents of the old location are forgotten/ignored and remain inaccessible (from Rust code). I'm afraid I don't understand how to "showcase what might happen" other than what I already wrote in the answer.

I see thanks a lot, also I asked this because i'm confused on one part, if we are bitwise copying the data then why the Test instance wasn't dropped after the function returned as the memory on the stack frame should be deallocated, but its done on main function

@kyles if we are bitwise copying the data then why the Test instance wasn't dropped - because that's the essential difference between copying and moving. When you copy (as with let b = a.clone()), you need to drop both the original and the copy. When you move it, you don't. Imagine let a = vec![1, 2, 3]; let b = a;. If we dropped a after the move bitwise-copied the ptr/length/capacity triple that is a, it would result in a double-free because both a and b have the same pointer. Instead, Rust does the right thing, and forgets about a (and doesn't let you access it). That's move.

Disregarding compiler optimizations, here's how the stack may look conceptually at various points in your examples:
Example 1
struct Test(u8);

impl Drop for Test {
   fn drop(&mut self) {
      println!("{} is dropped", self.0);
  }
}

fn main() {
   // Stack:
   // +-----+
   // | xxx | test
   // +-----+
   // | xxx | t
   // +-----+
   let test;
   {
       println!("step 1");
       let t = Test(1);
       // Stack:
       // +-----+
       // | xxx | test
       // +-----+
       // |  1  | t
       // +-----+
       println!("step 2");
       test = t;
       // Stack:
       // +-----+
       // |  1  | test
       // +-----+
       // | xxx | t (in practice the value is still "1", but
       // +-----+    this is now irrelevant and ignored)
   } 
   println!("{}", test.0);
   // Stack:
   // +-----+
   // |  1  | test
   // +-----+
   // | xxx | t
   // +-----+

   // - `drop (test)` is called implicitly here.
   // - `drop (t)` isn't called (and indeed cannot be called) since
   //   the corresponding space is considered unused.
}

Note that space is allocated on the stack only once at the beginning of the function and freed all at once when the function returns, even if some parts of the space may be unused at some points in time (denoted by xxx in the schematics above).
Note also that the optimizer may decide to merge the two allocations so that test and t have the same address and there will be no need to copy anything on the test = t line.
Example 2:
fn main() {
   // Stack:
   // +-----+
   // | xxx | test
   // +-----+
   println!("step 1");
   let test = create_struct();
   // Stack:
   // +-----+
   // |  1  | test
   // +-----+
   println!("step 2");
   println!("{}", test.0);
   // `drop (test)` is called implicitly here.
}

pub fn create_struct() -> Test {
   // Stack:
   // +-------+
   // | xxxxx | test (from the `main` stack frame)
   // +-------+
   // |  ptr  | code address from which the function was called
   // +-------+
   // | &test | address where the return value must be stored
   // +-------+
   Test(1)
   // Stack:
   // +-------+
   // |   1   | test (from the `main` stack frame)
   // +-------+
   // |  ptr  | code address from which the function was called
   // +-------+
   // | &test | address where the return value must be stored
   // +-------+
}

Note that the function calling convention is unspecified. I chose to show a convention where the caller passes the address of the return value as a hidden argument to the function, and where that argument is passed on the stack. Depending on the size of the return value, the compiler may also choose to:

Pass the address of the return value in a register instead of the stack
Allocate some space on the stack when calling a function so that the function can put the return value there, then move the return value to its final location after the function returns (similar to what I showed in example 1).
Put the return value in a register and let the caller decide where to store it.


I understand the first example now, as for the 2nd one, you are saying we only created one instabce and no copying has happened because we wrote the value directly on address of test, but can this function access memory in the stack that is outside of its stack frame?

If the 2nd choice was to happen, then we would see 2 drop printed not one? because the value will be dropped after function returns?

Yes a function can access memory anywhere if it's given a mut reference to that memory (explicitly or implicitly). This includes heap memory, static memory, and other function stack memory.

For the second example, if the compiler chose the second alternative that would not modify the program behaviour, so drop would still be called only once (exactly like the first example).

But if you say "move", that means we created Test on the function stack frame, and then shallow copied it after the function returns, now i'm talking about the memory allocated for Test on the function stack frame, what happens to it as you can't just say forget because it must deallocated as the function returned so we should see "drop".
I think the memory is deallocated only its not by calling "drop" because that would mean heap memory will be freed if we have a reference to it in our struct, which is not the case, so its like we are just removing a copy ?

@kyles as you can't just say forget because it must deallocated as the function returned so we should see "drop". - no, you only see "drop" for the code that does additional work to deconstruct the memory. Releasing of the memory itself is outside the domain of Drop::drop(), particularly for stack-allocated memory which happens by just retracting the stack pointer. So yes, you certainly can just forget something stack-allocated memory, and that's (conceptually) what happens to moved variables.

@kyles I think the memory is deallocated only its not by calling "drop" - this is essentially correct - deallocation and destruction are two separate things.
